# How can I fix my Login validation for JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, java, html, validation, authentication

I am trying to make a basic validation for my login form, but it doesn't seem to work.

Here is my Code: 
Script:

```
var attempt = 3; // Variable to count number of attempts.
// Below function Executes on click of login button.
function validate(){
    var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
    if ( email == "admin@gmail.com" && password == "1234"){
        alert ("Login successfully");
        window.location = "success.html"; // Redirecting to other page.
        return false;
    }
    else{
        attempt --;// Decrementing by one.
        alert("You have left "+attempt+" attempt;");
// Disabling fields after 3 attempts.
        if( attempt == 0){
            document.getElementById("username").disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("password").disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("submit").disabled = true;
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<form>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
                        <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group form-check">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1">
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">Check me out</label>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                </form>
```

P.S. I have included the script document in my HTML page.

Comment: You don't appear to be calling the `validate` function anywhere. And assuming you intend to attach it to the submit button, or the form's `submit` event, you will also need to prevent the default action (of submitting the form values to the current page, thereby forcing a reload). And I hope you're just doing this as an exercise to learn JS, because I have to point out in case you're unaware, this is *not* how to do a secure user authentication system :)

Comment: Of course I am aware of that. Anyone can just check the element and find the login details. This is more of a test than the actual login. I am still learning JS, that is why. It worked now. There was a small typing error:  document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", validate );

Comment: Cool, glad you got it fixed. You do occasionally see questions here from people who seem to think you *can* do user authentication on the client side so I thought it safest to check you weren't one of those. Apologies if it came off as patronising.

Comment: No not at all. It's good that you ask. This is a website for helping and being helped after all. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to bind the validate function to something. Assuming you would want to tie it to the submit button it would look something like this.

```
document.getElementsByTagName("button").addEventListener("click", validate );
```